# How to unbold and unhighlight the selected text in edittext android

Tags: java, android

Hi I am able to bold or highlight the selected text but when try to unhighlight or unbold in that bolded or highlighted text then it unbold or unhighlight the whole text. Please tell me what I am doing wrong with my code. Here is my code

```
private void highlightTextCondition() {
    int selectionStart = bodyText.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = bodyText.getSelectionEnd();
    if (selectionStart > selectionEnd) {
        int temp = selectionEnd;
        selectionEnd = selectionStart;
        selectionStart = temp;
    }

 if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = bodyText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;

        for (CharacterStyle span : str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, CharacterStyle.class)) {
            if (span instanceof BackgroundColorSpan)
                str.removeSpan(span);
            exists = true;
        }
        if (!exists) {
            str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        bodyText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
```